# Calculated column for selecting city to prepopulate with region

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, choice-field

If I have one column that allows me to select multiple cities from
A drop down box.

How can I set the next column to prepopulate with the region of this city in sharepoint?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @user107779, does my below response answers your question? let me know if you still need any help with it.

Comment: If answered, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use multiple selection choice columns in SharePoint calculated column formula.

So, if you are using SharePoint Online modern experience list forms, you have to customize the list forms using Power Apps to auto populate the columns based on selection in other fields.

**Documentations**:

1. [Customize SharePoint list form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-apps/get-started/create-your-first-custom-form)
2. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
3. [Auto populate Text box based on a Dropdown selected value in Sharepoint list column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Auto-populate-Text-box-based-on-a-Dropdown-selected-value-in/td-p/504158)